# Use of jsp generic variable using condition

Tags: html, jsp

i have a generic variable

```
 <c:set var="p" value="${ShoppingModel.ShoppingStatus}" />
```

then inside h2

```
    <h2 class= "${p=='Active'? 'orange' : p =='Closed' : 'red':'blue'}">  <c:out value="${p}" /></h2>
```

but this is not working, how to assign class variable with condition using jsp generic varible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demonstration.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            h2.orange{color:orange;}
            h2.red{color:red;}
            h2.blue{color:blue;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:set var="p" value='${"Active"}' />
        <h2 class="${p ==  'Active'? 'orange' : p == 'Closed'?'red':'blue'}">  <c:out value="${p}" /></h2>
        <c:set var="p" value='${"Closed"}' />
        <h2 class="${p == 'Active'? 'orange' : p == 'Closed'?'red':'blue'}">  <c:out value="${p}" /></h2>
        <c:set var="p" value='${"default"}' />
        <h2 class="${p == 'Active'? 'orange' : p == 'Closed'?'red':'blue'}">  <c:out value="${p}" /></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could be good to tell what did you do to have a working demonstration. It look like the problem come from the `c:set` but since you put hardcoded values, well you don't really help him.

Comment: The error was in the EL. The wrong syntax was used for the multi-layer ternary operator. I had to use some values in order to demonstrate.

Comment: It could be good to tell him ;) "past this code" is not a useful to OP. PS : Didn't notice this error, nice catch.